# Is it ok to brine an already cured ham?

Tags: brining, ham

I always make a ham on Christmas Eve and this year I was thinking of trying to get a little extra flavour in by brining it first.
However it is a shop bought, already cured ham.

I've looked around online and couldn't find anything in particular to say you should or shouldn't so I thought I'd ask here.

My main concern is that brining it might make it overly salty, and the other issue is would it even have any effect on the flavour at all considering it's most likely been wet cured already.

Comment: Pretty sure if you check the nutrition information on cured ham it's got plenty of sodium already, unlike an uncured turkey (whence the popularity of brining big holiday meat items seems to be at peak.) I can't imagine it would benefit much, as a result. but that does not rise to the level of being an answer, as I certainly have not tried it, and hopefully for you someone has and can answer based on experience, not speculation.

Comment: @Ecnerwal yeah, that's kind of what I was thinking. I thought of doing it without any salt, but that's probably not going to do much good either.

Comment: Depending what you're trying to achieve, marinating it (eg, wine or vinegar or pineapple juice and spices) could make a difference to the flavor, but the untested last minute experiment on a reliable holiday staple could go either way, and if it's not the good way that could be disappointing in the moment. Grab a *small* ham and experiment, if not now, some other time when it won't be a big deal if you don't like the result.

Comment: @Ecnerwal excellent points. I should probably have looked into it a little earlier if I really was serious about this. Not really enough time to experiment now.